# Python: Tkinter Checkbox does not visually update, when no command is set

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with my code:
I want to create n checkboxes in tkinter and some of them should be checked by default.
This is my code:

```
for i,cam in enumerate(scene.cameras):
    self.activCamVarList.append(tk.BooleanVar())
    
    
    button=tk.Checkbutton(self.cameraSettingsFrame,
        text=cam,bg=Colors.widget,
        fg=Colors.fontColor, 
        selectcolor=Colors.widget, 
        activebackground=Colors.widget,
        variable=self.activCamVarList[i]
    ) 
    self.cameraButtons.append(button)
    button.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=(0,15))
    if cam == self.scene.aCamera:
        button.select()
```

However if I run my code, all of the buttons are unchecked(the if statement works fine).
But when I add `command=lamdba:self` to my buttons, the code works fine. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Wild guess (in the absence of a [mcve]): you're not saving a reference to the object whose class definition contains this code; therefore `activeCamVarList` gets garbage-collected, and therefore all your `BooleanVar`s get garbage-collected.  And that's where the Checkbuttons were saving their state.  The `command=` you added contains a reference to `self`, and therefore keeps the object alive.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I understand my problem, next time I will give a better code example